# basic login user and session plus cookie

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT member FROM".$table_name."WHERE member=%s AND memberpwd=%s",$membername,$memberpassword);
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
{
     echo "Unable to select members";
     mysql_close();
     exit();
}
$rowNum=mysql_num_rows($result);
if(0!=$rowNum)
{
    session_start();
    $user=mysql_result($result,0,'member');
    $_SESSION['user']=$user;
    header('Location:index.php');
    echo "Welcome ".$user;
        exit();
}
```

I use that code to validate a login user and start his session but nothing is shown in the browser. I would also like the login user to appear in every page he visits, like a forums login member but I don't know how to use session with cookie to be stored somewhere so that he'll be remembered in each of his re-visits. This is the hardest part for me to do, could someone please help me ?

EDIT: Sorry, my knowledge of PHP just reaches and stops there-Session part. If I can have an ABC Session explained tutorial, that'll be really helpful, thank you.

Comment: You are WIDE OPEN for SQL Injection/hack.  Look into parameterizing your queries first and do it safely throughout, otherwise you'll be done before you begin by the first hacker.

Comment: Thank you, at present I only need things that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT
> >     (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code
> >     has already been set. ([header() on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))
>
> ```
> <?php
> header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
> /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
> exit;
> ?>
> ```

It is not displayed because of redirect. Place `echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user'];` in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$member` defined, there at the bottom.

`echo "Welcome ".$user;`

... should work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edit my post, the login form still results in the same blank page after posted.